# How to use a variable command in a sed expression

Tags: regex, bash, variables, sed

Testing for a simple script but I can't get this variable to cooperate with me. I've tried so many things, single quotes and doubles.

```
New=$(df -h)

sed -ie "200s|^.*$|"${NEW}"|g" "file.txt"
```

I'm trying to replace whatever is on line 200 of file.txt with the output of df -h pretty much.

Need help, if this has been asked before, sorry my brain is toasted and I'm not smart enough to comprehend.

most of the time i get an "unterminated `s'" error when I run the script. I'm thinking it's got something to do with the "{}" brackets around the variable and it being misread as something else in regex.

Comment: `New` != `NEW`.

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable same input (contents of `file.txt` before the script runs and output of `df -h`) and expected output (contents of `file.txt` after the script runs) so we can help you.

Comment: If you use GNU sed then `sed '200s/.*/df -h/e' file` is suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `df -h` has whitespace so you need to keep it quoted to prevent word splitting. Compare:

```
# wrong - ${NEW} is not inside the quotes on either its left or right hand sides 
sed -ie "200s|^.*$|"${NEW}"|g" "file.txt" 
# better - ${NEW} is within the double-quoted string
sed -ie "200s|^.*$|${NEW}|g" "file.txt"
# if ${NEW} contains newlines
sed -ie "200s|^.*$|${NEW//$'\n'/\\$'\n'}|g" "file.txt"
```

`awk` could be more readable/maintainable here as you don't have to interpolate the data into the command string:

```
awk -v subststr="${NEW}" -v lineno=200 '
  { if (NR == lineno) { print subststr } else {print $0} }
' file.txt > output.txt && mv output.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried the change and got the same result at the CLI. sed: -e expression #1, char 81: unterminated `s' command.

Comment: Probably your `du` output contains newlines as well. It _can_ be done with `sed` but probably don't.

Comment: Fair, newlines do break as well. I will address. But really the `awk` solution is probably the best in my opinion.

Comment: The second fix worked like a beautiful charm! thanks!! I have no clue how to read and interpret that expression but thanks a ton! Do you mind explaining what happened there?

Comment: Look for ANSI-C Quoting and Shell Parameter Expansion in the bash manual for detailed information. `$'\n'` expands to a newline character and `${var//pattern/replace}` replaces all occurrences of `pattern` in `var`, so the overall expansion replaces all newlines with escaped newlines to make `sed` happy. This is also another reason that `awk` may be easier to read, you don't have to do any special processing on the variable to make it digestible.

Comment: `sed` will still break if, for example, you have a filesystem with `|` in the name. You can address that in a similar way by escaping any instance of `|` in the variable, but the more edge cases you have to account for with escaping the harder it will be to read your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reliably escape variable values so they can be used in `sed` substitutions.  See [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/4154375) and [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407523/4154375).

If your input file is small (up to a megabyte should be OK on any modern system) and you've got Bash 4.0 (released in 2009) or later, there is an easy way to do what you want with pure Bash.  Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

readarray -O 1 -t lines <file.txt
lines[200]=$(df -h)
printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}" >file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ed` instead, especially if you haven't already executed `df -h`, because you can read the output directly into the file without an intermediate shell variable.

```
ed file.txt <<EOF
200r !df -h
200d
wq
EOF
```

The output of `df -h` is inserted between lines 200 and 201, and then line 200 is deleted.